# Get items from django model depending on session

Tags: python, django, session

I've got two models setup in django as follows:

```
class SessionTable(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name_id = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=40)
    session_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class NameTable(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
```

Depending on the session, I've got a view `add_to` which stores the `name_id` and `session_id` of the request in the table.

Now in my `sample_view`, I want to show `name` and `desc` of the selected `name_ids` for that particular session. For this I've done the following

```
def sample_view(request):
    rep = RequestContext(request)
    session = request.session.session_key
    prod = SessionTable.objects.filter(session_id__exact=session)
    name = []
    for a in prod:
        result_id = a.prod_id
        prods = NameTable.objects.filter(id__exact=result_id)
        name.insert(prods.name)
    return render_to_response('view.html', {'name': name}, rep)
```

but this isn't working at all. My approach seems to be wrong. How should I go about solving this?

Comment: There are at least two separate errors that will be generated just by the line `name.insert(prods.name)`. Did you try and solve any of those errors?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It gave me the `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'` error which I didn't understand since NameTable has an attribute called name. I solved this by using `get` instead of `filter` which worked. This gave me an error in number of arguments for insert. This I solved by using `append` instead of `insert`.

Comment: So what's the value of name in your code? Is it correct?

Comment: @m170897017, after this runs, `name` contains 1 element while `prod` contains 3

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `name=[]` outside function `sample_view()`, like this:

```
name = []
def sample_view(request):
    rep = RequestContext(request)
    session = request.session.session_key
    prod = SessionTable.objects.filter(session_id__exact=session)
    # name = []
    for a in prod:
        result_id = a.prod_id
        prods = NameTable.objects.filter(id__exact=result_id)
        name.insert(prods.name)
    return render_to_response('view.html', {'name': name}, rep)
```